# 365 1/4 days folks!

Tags: discussion, beta-phase

[image: Yearling Badges are out!]

Yep. It's been one year folks. Three hundred and sixty-five days. And add a quarter. Or add one. I can't remember if this year was a leap year or not :P

So... Since we need questions... Wait this is meta. We don't need questions.

Okay.

### Ideas on how to celebrate folks?

Comment: Three six five dot two four two five!

Comment: @bjb568 2425? Am I reading this wrong?

Comment: The Gregorian calendar has 365.2425 days per year. 365 for a regular year. 365.25 for leap years. 365.24 for every 100 years when there isn't a leap year. 365.2425 for every 400 years when there *is*, again, a leap year.

Comment: The science is getting to me! I'm being swamped by science! Cookies! Help me!

Answer (score 3):

With more than 800 questions, a 97% answer rate and ~170 visitors per day, how about celebrating by graduating the site out of beta?

Comment: This would be awesome ;) Although we aren't meeting the questions per day threshold. Is this still enough to graduate? (Also 170 visitors per day isn't enough either - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82234/open-source)

Comment: @TimMalone What happens if we don't ever meet those guidelines? Are we shut down?

Comment: @EMBLEM Nope, as long as moderation is taking place (ie flags are being dealt with), we won't be shut down. But it might take longer to graduate.

Answer (score -1):

I'd love to celebrate by having the CMs fulfil their promise to visit us and answer our questions about changing the site's name.

But I guess I should propose something somewhat more realistic ;)

Comment: I'm frustrated enough with that situation to upvote this, which is uncharacteristic of me. Believe me when I say we've been trying to get someone to come back and tell us *something*, even if it's just "sorry, no can do".